# Disagreement between p-values, BCa confidence intervals, and effect sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value, bootstrap, effect-size, paired-data

I conducted a paired samples t-test to assess the differences several variables before and after an intervention. The sample size is very small (n = 8). For one the variables, I have some confusing findings:
p = .132
Bca 95% CI = [-169.24, -7.010].
d = .60

So, while there is no statistical significance according to the p value, the BCa CI does not contain 0 (and thus, it seems that the intervention had some statistical influence). In addition, there was a medium to large effect size observed.

However, this variable has relatively high SDs (M1 = 197.77, SD1 = 92.97; M2 = 283.98, SD2 = 160.03). It seems to me that the results are inconclusive. My question is: Should I reject or accept the null hypothesis based on my findings?

Comment: Did you bootstrap the sample? That would be the only way you could get a BCa confidence interval. If you are doing a paired t test why would you choose to bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, bootstrapping was performed to provide a more robust population estimate of the difference between the means.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that p=0.132 is the p-value of the t-test (and that t-test is applicable), you should accept the null hypothesis.

Now things could go wrong if your assumptions of t-test are not valid, which in this case should be non-normality (since you do not have a large sample size). If you know that your data comes from a normal distribution, your t-test is completely valid.

My hunch is that if you plot your data, you might find high skewedness, which would violate the t-test. Honestly, I wouldn't trust the bootstrap CI much either because bootstrapping on 8 samples isn't going to give you much information about the sampling distribution. My suggestion would be to try non-parametric methods.

Comment: does your answer change for a different type of analysis? like estimating indirect effect in the context of a path analysis using bca ci?

Comment: +1 I don’t trust bootstrap for 8 samples.